# Unable to locate error with PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently unable to explain why this code is throwing multiple errors from:

Syntax error or access violation: 1064
Base table or view not found: 1146

I've looked at other threads and I have tried multiple different variations but am still unable to locate what I'm doing wrong.

I've done this multiple times before but I cannot for the life of me figure this out, I'm fatigued but it's getting on now...

```
    $insert = $connection -> prepare("INSERT INTO `:table` (`start`, `stop`) VALUES (:start, :stop);");

    $insert -> bindParam(':table', $table, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
    $insert -> bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
    $insert -> bindParam(':stop',  $stop,  PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);

    $insert -> execute();
```

Comment: [You can't bind table names.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

Comment: You might be able to bind table names with EMULATE_PREPARES